# i can't move my player by clicking button

Tags: unity-game-engine, eventtrigger

[image]

My player GameObject is AlienPlayer
i want to move player by click of the button
code works on keyboard controls but not on click of a button
**This is my update():**

```
void Update()
{
    
    movement = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    if (movement > 0f) {
        
        left();
    }
    else if (movement < 0f) {
        
        right();
    }
    else {
      rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (0,rigidBody.velocity.y);
    }
    
    
    if (moveLeft) { left(); }
    else if (moveRight) { right(); }
    
}



public void left()
{
    
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement*speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
    //rigidBody.AddForce(transform.forward * speed, ForceMode2D.Force);
    transform.localScale = new Vector2(2f, 2f);

}
public void right()
{
    
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
    transform.localScale = new Vector2(-2f, 2f);

}
```

**And this for event trigger:**

```
public void LeftBtnDown()
{
    moveLeft = true;
}
public void LeftBtnUp()
{
    moveLeft = false;
}
public void RightBtnDown()
{
    moveRight = true;
}
public void RightBtnUp()
{
    moveRight = false;
}
```

**I want to make this control for android **

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be logically functional, my first guess would be that you don't have an event system any where in your scene.

You can create one simply by clicking on the + in the hierarchy menu -> UI -> EventSystem.

I don't believe the code is the problem, but if the EventSystem does not turn out to be the issue, you could try changing your Update method to this:

```
void Update()
{

    movement = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    if (movement > 0f || moveLeft) {
        
        left();
    }
    else if (movement < 0f || moveRight) {
        
        right();
    }
    else {
      rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (0,rigidBody.velocity.y);
    }
    
}
```

If that does not work, I would need additional information to help you.

Comment: EventSystem is there in the Scene ,and i did what u said in the code ,ask me annything which might get this done

Comment: I would start by debugging the LeftBtnDown, LeftBtnUp, RightBtnDown and RightBtnUp methods to make sure that they’re being called (just call a Debug.Log with a specific message in each function)

Comment: Also while you’re at it, check that there are no other UI objects blocking the buttons, such as another canvas(Which I’m not 100% sure if they can eat inputs) or other invisible elements. If there are other UI blocking them, I would attempt to disable them and see if the buttons now work.